# Search multiple CSVs for one particular value

Tags: python, pandas, csv, append, glob

I have a directory of CSV files that list fruits and there quantities, and I want to search all those and create a new CSV that only has a particular fruit (e.g., "apple").

**list1.csv**

```
| Name     | Qty |
| -------- | --- |
| apple    |15   | 
| apple    |50   |
| mango    |20   | 
| grapes   |49   |
```

**list2.csv**

```
| Name     | Qty |
| -------- | --- |
| apple    |25   | 
| apple    |50   |
| Banana   |34   |
| mango    |20   | 
| grapes   |49   |
```

**list3.csv**

```
| Name     | Qty |
| -------- | --- |
| apple    |125   | 
| apple    |530   |
| mango    |20   | 
| grapes   |49   |
```

I want, for "apple":

**new.csv**

```
| Name     | Qty |
| -------- | --- |
| apple    |15   | 
| apple    |50   |
| apple    |25   | 
| apple    |50   |
| apple    |125  | 
| apple    |530  |
```

```
import pandas as pd
import glob, os
path = ("E:/Data/Fdata")
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
li=[]
for filename in all_files:
    df=pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    ndf = df[df["Name"].str.contains("Apple")]
    li.append(ndf)
    ndf.to_csv("E:/Data/Fdata/onlyapple.csv", index=True)
```

Comment: Move `ndf.to_csv` outside the `for` loop. i.e. remove the indentation.

Comment: it's not working that way also

Comment: What is "not working"? Provide an example of your csv file, your current output and your expected output.

Comment: list1.csv
apple  15 500
apple  50 400
mango  20 500
grapes 49 855


list2.csv
apple  15 500
mango  20 500
apple  50 400
mango  20 500
grapes 49 855


I want a new.csv in which I want 
apple  15 500
apple  50 400
apple  15 500
apple  50 400

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Read all your csv files to a `master` DataFrame
2. Filter on the "Name" you want and write `to_csv`

```
import os
import pandas as pd

master = pd.DataFrame()
for file in [f for f in os.listdir(".") if f.endswith("csv")]:
    master = master.append(pd.read_csv(file), ignore_index=True)
    
master[master["Name"].eq("apple")].reset_index(drop=True).to_csv("onlyapple.csv")
```

###### onlyapple.csv:

```
,Name,quantity,price
0,apple,15,500
1,apple,50,400
2,apple,15,500
3,apple,50,400
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it without Pandas:

```py
import csv
import glob

fruit = 'apple'

final = []
header = []

for file in glob.glob('./*.csv'):
    with open(file, newline='') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        header = next(reader)  # header should be same for each file

        for row in reader:
            if row[0] == fruit:
                final.append(row)

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(header)    # use the last file's header
    writer.writerows(final)
```

And here's how to do it without code using [GoCSV](https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv)'s commands, **stack** (to stack your files one on top of each other) and **filter** (to filter out only the rows you want):

```sh
gocsv stack *.csv | gocsv filter -c Name -eq apple
```

Comment: The code above gives the required output when the directory has around 100 csv. But for more than that(like for 700 or so, my work directory) it's giving a blank csv as an output.

Comment: Hey, that's a bummer about the bigger list of files. I just mocked up 1000 files, and it ran fine. Are you using Windows? Maybe try `[f for f in os.listdir('.') if f.endswith('csv')]` instead of glob.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Windows. and tried [f for f in os.listdir('.') if f.endswith('csv')] as well. This also gives a blank csv with only the header row. and it's taking a bit longer to execute. Any suggestions?

Comment: If the header is there, that means the files are being read. Add some print() statements in the loop to ensure all the files are being looped over, opened by the CSV reader. Also, did you change the fruit? If the fruit you specified isn’t in the files, that would also result in an output file with only the header.

Comment: No, the fruit name is there in the files. it's working on less number of files. only when there are more files, it's just kinda hanging. Is it a memory problem, or something?